# && and || in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I've tried doing some research on this topic but theres a suprisingly low amount of information. I have a switch statement, and I want a certain block to trigger if one of 2 conditions is true. I could just have identical blocks checking each condition, but it looks kind of redundant.

```
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0:
     //Identical Code
     break;

case KeyEvent.VK_INSERT:
     //Identical Code
     break;
```

Is there a way to combine the two statements to avoid repeating identical code?

Comment: && is not possible in a variable singular state.

Answer (score 7):

```
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0:
case KeyEvent.VK_INSERT:
     //Identical Code
     break;
```

Comment: It makes sense thinking about how switch statements flow, I was thinking something along the lines of `case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0 || KeyEvent.VK_INSERT:` whoops Thanks!

Comment: Now I'd like to suggest you please add some explanation, however terse. Code-only answers tend to be only slightly more useful than link-only answers. Quick, befoe Abhi overtakes you :-)

Comment: Abhi is welcome to overtake me... I'm not spending any more time on such a trivial question. :P

Comment: @Graham: There is no overtaking here. Just trying to help a bit. I am just a slow typer. Agree with you on the trivial part. Will type faster than you next time, though :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is known as `FallThrough`
Look at the fallthrough demos in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

```
case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0:
case KeyEvent.VK_INSERT:
     //Identical Code
     break;
```

Comment: This is literally identical to the other answer.

Comment: @Yann4: no way. That other answer has a different author, and far more votes :-)

Comment: @Yann4 well it was posted like 3 seconds after the other one.

Comment: @user1071777 then edited to be identical :P. See, now it's better, and my -1 is now a +1.